# Why are lithium-ion batteries stored at 50% voltage and not a lower voltage?

Tags: lithium-ion, battery-chemistry, battery-storage

I understand that a higher voltage causes more degradation of the material in the cell, but I'm curious as to why the typical storage voltage is not lower than 50%.

I've always assumed that the lower the voltage, the less material degradation, but that starting a storage cycle with a voltage too low runs the risk of dropping the voltage to a point where the cell cannot be recharged, but I haven't been able to find a definitive reference for this.

Comment: Batteries are not stored at 3.8V; they are stored at 50-60% charged. The resulting voltage is secondary and can be anything depending on fine chemistry of particular cells.

Comment: @Ale..chenski, I updated the question to reflect.  Thanks for the heads-up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I've always assumed that the lower the voltage, the less material
>   degradation, but that starting a storage cycle with a voltage too low
>   runs the risk of dropping the voltage to a point where the cell cannot
>   be recharged, but I haven't been able to find a definitive reference
>   for this.

A definitive answer is difficult because few studies have been done that are freely available, and the results from one particular cell type may not be applicable to others.

I found a study on [Aging of Lithium-Ion Batteries in Electric Vehicles](https://battery-dynamics.de/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/Keil-Aging-of-Lithium-Ion-Batteries-in-Electric-Vehicles.pdf) which tested Panasonic NCR18650PD Li-ion cells. The results show that storing at 3.45 V causes less degradation than 3.7 V, so your assumption is correct for normal operating voltages. At 3.45 V the remaining capacity is very small (probably less than 1%), so your other assumption (that leaving too little charge may risk dropping into over-discharge) is also correct.

[image]

Another interesting thing they found was a big jump in degradation above 55% charge. Storing at 50% charge was not much worse than lower voltages, but 60% and above was much worse. This was attributed to changes in chemical composition of the cell at different charge states, so a cell with different chemistry may not react the same.

[image]

Comment: The link is dead. Do you perhaps have an alternative? Sounds like an interesting study.

Comment: I found the original at the [author's website](https://battery-dynamics.de/en/dr-peter-keil/) and have updated the link.

Answer (score 0):

In short, lower is better, but there is a limit. Voltages both too low (below 2.7V) and too high will damage Li-Ion cells, and they are best kept at "happy medium" levels. Also, there is self-discharge (5% in 24h, then 1–2% per month, plus 3% for safety circuit if there is one) which all battery chemistries have, and higher level charge helps when storing a cell/battery for a longer period of time (including waiting on store shelves to be purchased).
 According to "Battery University" (https://batteryuniversity.com), the lower the "depth of discharge", the longer the cell life, and a 50% "DoD" (between 30% and 80% charge level) gives the best compromise between useful capacity and lifetime.
Using the whole cell's capacity, you can get maybe 1000-2000 charge-discharge cycles, but using only 50% of its capacity you can get around 10000 cycles.
The same source does say the same thing you say here, namely that the higher voltages degrade a Li-Ion cell.
 Furthermore, a voltage below 2.7V will cause irreversible damage to the cell and a reduction in its capacity, so that should NEVER be allowed to happen with a Li-Ion cell.
So, according to this information, the ideal charge (or SoC - state of charge) level is around 40-50% which is below the damaging "high voltage" and at the same time gives plenty of "headroom" for self-discharge which would eventually bring the cell down to dangerously low levels.

References:
"BU-204: How do Lithium Batteries Work?"
https://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/lithium_based_batteries
"BU-409: Charging Lithium-ion"
https://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/charging_lithium_ion_batteries
"BU-808: How to Prolong Lithium-based Batteries"
https://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/how_to_prolong_lithium_based_batteries
(This is the most relevant link to your question)

Comment: Thanks, I don't think that's quite the answer I'm looking for.  I'm curious as to whether a lower voltage is better, and why.

Comment: I have updated my answer with more info, and will add more later. Basically there is a low limit where it becomes even more damaging to the cell than the high levels, so that's why the manufacturers charge them up to give them much more time before they slowly lose charge and go too low.

Answer (score 0):

A very quick and dirty high level summary is at above 3.8v the battery needs to "deflate", anything below 3.8, the battery needs to "inflate". Basically stressing the cell, 3.8v or it's nominal voltage, is the happy medium where it can just rest. Storing cells undercharged is not ideal but not a huge deal, storing them at charge in my experience causes huge degredation in cell quality, even if stored for more than a day or two. This usually is reset after the next charge but does leave lasting damage.

I liion and lipo, aything below 2.7v results in permenant damage. You typically want to stop at 3.3v. Depending on your application, you would not want to go below 3v since current draw at this low a voltage on a cell causes it to sag significantly more, potentially dropping it below 2.7v. On a lipo, do notbring it down past 3v. On Li ion, 2.7v.

Answer (score 0):

Probably a lower voltage would be a bit better. But the existing practice still preserves battery longevity pretty well.

Also, you need to leave room for self-discharge without getting too low. The batteries may sit for some time after leaving the factory. And once the cells have been assembled into a battery pack, there will be some type of protection circuit that consumes a small amount of current. And if the battery pack is then installed into a device which will be shipped to a consumer, there may be additional standby current consumed by the device. But the hope and expectation is that the device will at least power on when it gets to the consumer, even if it has been six months since the battery left the factory. Marketing doesn't think it is a good out of box experience if the device is DOA and has to be charged before it can be used.

I should actually add that if it were up to marketing, the devices would be shipped fully charged. They don't care about longevity issues. The reason the batteries ship at 45% state-of-charge (SOC) is because that is the maximum that is allowed by the shipping regulations. I guess the batteries are less hazardous when they are at low/middle SOC.